# Admissible Heurstic for A*

Tags: algorithm, search

I was reading the book: **Artificial intelligence a modern approach - third edition**  and regarding the admissible heuristic functions they gave this definition:

"Admissible heuristic is one that never overestimates the cost to reach the goal"

While on Wikipedia they mentioned that:

"A heuristic function is said to be admissible if it never overestimates the cost of reaching the goal, i.e. the cost it estimates to reach the goal is not higher than the lowest possible cost from the current point in the path"

But in the book they didn't say "the optimal" or "the lowest path"

So the admissible is when h is lower-or equal to any path or the optimal one?

Comment: When h is lower than or equal to "the cost", which is the cost of the optimal path.

Comment: okay thank you - thought that true cost means a real cost not only a best

Comment: Note also that "lower than the cost of any path" and "lower than the cost of the lowest-cost path" are completely equivalent (except the former is slightly ambiguous and might mean something else).

Comment: "lower than the cost of any path": when I wrote it I meant not only the optimal one if there are multiple paths with different costs, it is enough to be lower than any one of them and lower than the lowest, how can they considered as equivalent ?

Comment: "lower than the cost of any path" is ambiguous in English; it might mean "lower than all possible costs of paths" or "lower than at least one path". If it means "lower than all possible costs of paths", then it is equivalent to "lower than the lowest cost".

Comment: okay thank you again, so it should be lower than the optimal one to be admissible

Answer (score 0):

For the a* algorithm to be admissible the estimation needs to be lower than any real value. The rule `h(n) < h*(n)`, where `h` is the function for the estimation for node `n` and `h*` are the real cost for that node, must always be given.

Example:

You got a point `D` which can be accessed from the Points `A, B` and `C`. `A` to `D` cost 10, `B` to `D` cost 5 and `C` to `D` cost 8. The estimation for `D` is 7. Now, the estimation is lower than to cost of `A` to `D` and `C` to `D`, so for these paths the rule is given. However not for `B` to `D`, so the algorithm here is not admissible. If `B` to `D` on the other hand would cost 9, or more than the estimation, the rule `h(n) < h*(n)` would be given for each connection. and therefore the algorithm would be admissible.